# What is the vectorization of a 3D matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, computer-science

According to [this](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Vectorization_(mathematics)), vectorization of a 2D matrix M=$[\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d\\ \end{array}]$ is Vec(M) = $[\begin{array}{c} a \\ c \\ b \\ d \end{array}]$.
So, what will be the vectorization of a 3D matrix like K=[$[\begin{array}{cc}a & b \\ c & d\\ \end{array}]$, $[\begin{array}{cc}e & f \\ g & h\\ \end{array}]$, $[\begin{array}{cc}i & j \\ k & l\\ \end{array}]$]

Is it Vec(K) = $[\begin{array}{c} a \\ c \\ b \\ d \\e\\g\\f\\h\\i\\k\\j\\l \end{array}]$ or Vec(K) = $[\begin{array}{c} a \\ c \\ e \\ g \\i\\k\\b\\d\\f\\h\\j\\l \end{array}]$

PS: I actually need it for something CS related, but this is a math concept so I am asking it here.

Comment: I don't suppose it matters as long as you are consistent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vecc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\modd#1{\op{mod}\LR{#1}}
\def\divv#1{\op{div}\LR{#1}}
\def\A{{\cal A}}
\def\AA{{\large\mathbb A}}
$For $\sf 3D$ and higher matrices, it helps to use
($\o$-based) index notation.

First, consider the $\sf 2D$ case: $\quad A\in\R{m\times n},\;a\in\R{mn}$
$$\eqalign{
A_{ij} &\implies a_q \\
q &\;\;=\;\; i + m\LR{j-\o} \qquad\qquad\qquad \\\\
}$$
For the $\sf 3D$ case: $\quad\A\in\R{m\times n\times p},\;a\in\R{mnp}$

First combine $(i,j)\to q\;$ using the mapping shown above
$\;\A_{ijk} \implies A_{qk}$

then combine $(q,k)\to r\;$ with a similar index mapping
$$\eqalign{
A_{qk} &\implies a_{r} \\
r &\;\;=\;\; q + mn\LR{k-\o} \qquad\qquad\quad \\
}$$
Or in a single step
$$\eqalign{
\A_{ijk} &\implies a_{r} \\
r &\;\;=\;\; i + m\LR{j-\o} + mn\LR{k-\o} \\\\
}$$
Generalizing to higher dimensions: $\quad\AA\in\R{m\times n\times p\times\ldots}$
$$\eqalign{
\AA_{ijk\ell\ldots} &\implies a_{r} \\
r &\;\;=\;\; i + m\LR{j-\o} + mn\LR{k-\o}  + mnp\LR{\ell-\o} + \ldots \\
}$$

---

This is the indexing scheme that numerically focused computer languages like $\sf Fortran{\rm\;and\;}Julia$ use behind the scenes
for their multi-dimensional arrays. It is called **column-major** ordering.

Other (general purpose) languages like $\sf C/C^{++}$ don't have multi-dimensional arrays. They use arrays of arrays to fake it, and end up with **row-major** ordering.

Comment: Thanks. I am using python so I was using reshape which I guess uses row-major order unless you specify fortran like ordering using the 'F' flag. I was using it for PCA analysis and as the commentator Paul said I think in the end it did not matter since I was using the same logic to transform it back to the original dimensions after applying the transformation. But still, it's pretty cool to know this.